# Evaluate ratio test for series

Tags: calculus

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(n!)^4}{(4n)!}$$

Applying ratio test

$$\frac{\frac{(n!)^4}{(4n)!}}{\frac{((n+1)!)^4}{(4n+4)!}}$$ 
Simplification step 1

$$\frac{(n!)^4(4n+4)(4n+3)(4n+2)(4n+1)}{((n+1)(n!))^4}$$
Further simplification

$$\frac{(4n+4)(4n+3)(4n+2)(4n+1)}{(n+1)^4}$$

From these point if i were to expand both the numerator and denominator, i would get >1 which is divergent but the answer says it is convergent

Comment: The first fraction you have written is upside down: you need to look at $a_{n+1}/a_n$.

Comment: how did you get $\frac{(n!)^4(4n+4)(4n+3)(4n+2)(4n+1)}{((n+1)(n!))^4}$ :O would you mind to check it again

Answer (score 1):

your  first expression is actually should be the other way
$$\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\dfrac{\dfrac{((n+1)!)^4}{(4n+4)!}}{\dfrac{(n!)^4}{(4n)!}}$$
$$=\frac{((n+1)!)^4(4n)!}{(4n+4)!(n!)^4}$$
$$=\frac{(n+1)^4}{(4n+4)(4n+3)(4n+2)(4n+1)}$$
$$=\frac{(n+1)^3}{4(4n+3)(4n+2)(4n+1)}$$

Can you conclude now?

Answer (score 0):

It should be the reciprocal of your very last expression and from this you get the limit = 1/64 < 1 ==> convergent.